# How to extract month and year from MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Here is my query `SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM <date>) FROM <table>;`

Output of this query is **201309**

But how to get it like **Sep-2013** , and that too as a date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT date_format(curdate(), '%b-%Y')
```

[DATEFORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/22360)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT CONCAT(MONTHNME(<date>), "-", YEAR(<date>)  FROM <table>;
```